# pandas.Timestamp.floor gives different results

Tags: python, pandas

I am running pandas 1.50

Below, I am running the same code for 2 different timestamps, and getting 2 different answers.

```
def test(now):
    now = pd.Timestamp(now)
    floored = now.floor(pd.Timedelta("48 hours"))
    diff = now - floored

    print(f"{now}, {interval}, {floored}, {diff}")

test('2023-10-18 23:59:03.793642')
test('2023-10-11 23:59:03.793642')
```

In the `test` function I floor the timestamp to a 48 hour interval, and then calculate the timedelta difference between the original timestamp and the floored timestamp.

The first timestamp floors to midnight on the same day (so to a 24 hour interval).
The second timestamp floors to midnight on the previousday (so to a 48 hour interval - as requested).

**Output:**

> ```
> 2023-10-18 23:59:03.793642, 48 hours, 2023-10-18 00:00:00, 0 days 23:59:03.793642
> 2023-10-11 23:59:03.793642, 48 hours, 2023-10-10 00:00:00, 1 days 23:59:03.793642
> ```

What is happening here?

How come I get different results?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`now.floor(pd.Timedelta("48 hours"))` doesn't floor **2 days ago**, it floors to the previous multiple of 48h since epoch.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

dates = pd.date_range('2023-10-01', '2023-10-10', freq='1h')
ax = plt.subplot()
plt.xticks(rotation=45)
ax.plot(dates, dates.floor(pd.Timedelta("48 hours")))
```

[image]

You probably should use a [`DateOffset`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.tseries.offsets.DateOffset.html):

```
def test(now):
    now = pd.Timestamp(now)
    floored = (now-pd.DateOffset(days=2)).floor('D')
    diff = now - floored

    print(f"{now}, {floored}, {diff}")

test('2023-10-18 23:59:03.793642')
test('2023-10-11 23:59:03.793642')
```

Output:

```
2023-10-18 23:59:03.793642, 2023-10-16 00:00:00, 2 days 23:59:03.793642
2023-10-11 23:59:03.793642, 2023-10-09 00:00:00, 2 days 23:59:03.793642
```

Graphical comparison:

[image]

Comment: Wow, just wow - thank you - this is so incredibly useful to know!

Comment: > floors to the previous multiple of 48h since epoch - this blows my mind. Is this considered intuitive? I don't know - maybe I'm thinking about it wrong?

Comment: @Steve if you make the analogy with flooring numbers this actually makes sense. For instance `32.9//2*2` and `33.9//2*2` both give `32`